# Free tool for create an exe

Tags: java, launch4j

Is there any free tool similar to Launch4j which bundles jre and don't require internet connection to download the jre and run the exe.

Comment: Do you really want the user to install a new JRE with every application he installs?

Comment: Distributing an app. off CD(/DVD/USB/floppy disk/magnetic tape/other portable media..) is more expensive than distributing it off the internet.  And don't forget that Netbook users will find it easier to download, than plug in a USB drive (gotta' find that 'black-recess-on-black cover').  I can't see the attraction of a (Windows specific) .exe coming off hard media in this millennium.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a suitable JRE isn't installed on the target machine, no Java executable wrapper is going to work. If a suitable JRE *is* on the machine, no executable wrapper that I know of would try to download a JRE.

There's a nice survey [here](http://www.excelsior-usa.com/articles/java-to-exe.html) of alternative approaches, including ahead-of-time compilers (that turn your jar into native code), installers that can bundle a JRE, and other ideas.

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is -> http://jsmooth.sourceforge.net/

Comment: hi rit,it will go for net if the user doesn't have installed jvm in him machine, i need a tool which don't need internet connection.i need to wrap jre

Comment: Ben Ten, what if you modified the source so that it checked for the JRE install, and if it wasn't found then it installs from a specified location on the CD? The issue with this is that you might be installing an outdated version with security holes though.

Comment: ok. sorry thought that the user has preinstalled java. but as the other commentres already wrote, i don't think it is a good idea. one other solution would be, that you create a small setup.bat which checks for Java installation, if not found then install it from the disk, if found, copy the generated exe file to the hard disk, create symlinks, ...